# Como enviar el resultado de dos consultas por AJAX en laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Buenas noches estoy usando laravel 5.6 y deseo hacer una petición de datos por ajax mediante un id y con este obtener el resultado de dos consultas. Mi preguntas es como puedo responder a la petición ajax con el resultado de las consultas.

Estas son mis consultas que estan en el controlador:

```
 $compras =DB::table('compras')
            ->join('proveedors', 'compras.id_proveedor', '=', 'proveedors.id_proveedor')
            ->select('id_compra','proveedors.nombre AS Empresa','fecha_compra','descripcion','estado')
            ->where('id_compra', '=', $id)
            ->get();
    $inventario=DB::table('inventarios')
            ->join('tipo_materials', 'inventarios.id_tipo_material', '=', 'tipo_materials.id_tipo_material')
            ->join('almacens', 'inventarios.id_almacen', '=', 'almacens.id_almacen')
            ->select('id_item','tipo_materials.descripcion AS Material','rango_inicial','rango_final','serie','cantidad','precio_unitario','observaciones','almacens.descripcion AS Almacen')
            ->where('id_compra', '=', $id)
            ->get();
```

Como podria retornar esta respuesta??

```
 return response()->json(
                 ??????????    
                 );
```

Comment: pudieras hacerlo return response()->json(['compras' => $compras, 'inventario' => $inventario]);

Comment: Muchisimas gracias realmente funciono como me indicaste te quedo muy agradecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer lo que quieres te comento que, el método JSON acepta como argumento un array asociativo de modo que puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
return response()->json(['compras' => $compras, 'inventario' => $inventario]);
```

> Donde el valor entre comillas es la clave y la variable es el valor
>   asignado